# JQuery Append variable to the URL when using $.get()

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, get, sinatra

I'm building an app and currently I have a bunch of links that will increment a counter when pressed, then the link disappears.

The HAML looks like this :

```
.button
   %a
      %img{:src => "a.jpg"}
.button
   %a
      %img{:src => "b.jpg"}
.button
   %a
      %img{:src => "c.jpg"}
```

When I press the button, the Javascript looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".button > a").click(function(event) {
      $(this).hide("slow");
      event.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

I want to make an ajax call to a link that will call a method and increment a counter next to the image (not shown in the above html) without making the url immediately apparent using $.get(). I know how to grab the src attribute and store it into a variable, but how do I put the variable into the URL parameter of the $.get() function?

The URL that increments the counter is $.get("up/a.jpg") ... but I need the "a.jpg" part to be a variable.

EDIT: I don't know how to grab the src attribute for the individual image I am sending the get function for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you have two parts to your problem:

1. Getting and storing a.jpg in a variable.
2. Pushing that into the URL after the up/ part.

Well, Step 2 is easy. Say you manage to pull out a.jpg into a variable called "thevariable".

You could just create a url using:

```
var url = 'up/'+thevariable;
$.get(url)...;
```

Now to pull out a.jpg and store it in a variable - you have multiple options:

1. Use a regex
2. Call split on the entire image src on / and pull out the last part.
3. Store the a.jpg part in another part of your HAML code by adding an additional attribute and pulling that out using jQuery. You could call it data-url (twitter does this too..)

Choose your sauce :)

Comment: Part 1, getting a.jpg I can just use 
$(this).find(".button img").attr("src")

The problem is how to get the right variable for the right button I am clicking.

Comment: Nvm

I used a combination of $(this).parent().prev().attr() because of the way my actual HAML is set up... everything works now. Thank you!

Comment: One of the tags for the question is is Sinatra, so in the route definition you could use a named param or a regex, e.g. `get "/up/:count" do |count|` see http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Routes for ideas/examples.